# Escape character with double qoutes inside escape charcter with double qoutes in shell script

Tags: shell

I have created a shell script like this, but I'm getting syntax error in grant command. Please can someone help me?

```
ssh -t qbadmin@10.3.2.0 '
 su root -c "
   echo \"Give db name :\";
   read db_name;
   echo \"Give password :\";
   read db_pass;
   host=localhost;
   sql1=\"create database \$db_name;\";
   sql2=\"grant all on \${db_name}.* to \${db_name}@\${host} identified by \"\${db_pass}\";\";
   sql3=\"\${sql1}\${sql2}\";
   echo \"==============\";
   mysql -u root -p -e \"\${sql3}\";
 ";
'
```

Comment: You give `GRANTS` on DB objects to a specific `user`, and not to a database name! Modify your statement like this `sql2=\"grant all on \${db_name}.* to \${user_name}@\${host} identified by \"\${db_pass}\";\";`

Comment: MYSql will automatically create a mysql user with username whatever we are given.Here db_name is variable which holds a string value and mysql will create a mysql user with username as same as db_name.

Comment: Here I think the problem is with the \" character before and after \$db_pass in the grant command.

Comment: That is some really hairy shell script to deal with.  You've got so many levels of command to deal with that getting the right number of backslashes and double quotes in the right places is really nasty.  I'd run miles to avoid having to do that!

Comment: My aim was to run the shell script in my local machine to login as normal user and turns to the root user for executing mysql commands.Here in this special case, through SSH, login as root user is disabled in server.So I needed to login as normal user to the server through SSH and then turn to root user for executing mysql commands.This is what i needed to do by shell script.I needed a single shell script and i have create it and had run it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

By putting `"\\\""` before and after `\${db_pass}` in the grant command, I solved the issue.  The grant command worked nicely without any syntax errors!

Thanks all for your support.

```
ssh -t qbadmin@10.3.2.0 '
 su root -c "
   echo \"Give db name :\";
   read db_name;
   echo \"Give password :\";
   read db_pass;
   host=localhost;
   sql1=\"create database \$db_name;\";
   sql2=\"grant all on \${db_name}.* to \${db_name}@\${host} identified by "\\\""\${db_pass}"\\\"";\";
   sql3=\"\${sql1}\${sql2}\";
   echo \"==============\";
   mysql -u root -p -e \"\${sql3}\";
 ";
'
```